# Count the number of colored cell on each row

Tags: excel

I want to have the number of colored cell on each row.
***Example:***
[image]

At the end, I should see :

```
2 

0

0

0

0

0

1
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If the color is applied by conditional formatting, recreate the conditional format logic and use COUNTIFS.

Comment: I did use conditional formatting yes, but I don't understand your advice @BigBen

Comment: What are the details of the conditional formatting?

Comment: if dates are between 1 dec 2022 and 31 dec 2024, highlight in red

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A1:C1,">=2022-12-1",A1:C1","<=2024-12-31")`